# Pass string to angular method from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to add some predefined colors for the user to choose. I made a $scope array with the colors and created buttons by the elements of the array. Each button has an ng-click attribute where I want to call a method on the controller that should handle the passed color property.

My html:

```
<button ng-repeat="color in colors" style="background-color:{{color}};" ng-click="ChangeBgColor(color)"></button>
```

And the controller:

```
 $scope.colors = ['#ddd', '#b2b2b2', '#0c60ee', '#0a9dc7', '#28a54c', '#e6b500', '#e42112', '#6b46e5', '#111', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'green', 'brown', 'lightblue'];
 $scope.ChangeBgColor = function(selectedColor)
   {
     console.log(selectedColor);
     $scope.selectedProduct.bgcolor = selectedColor;  
   }
```

The console.log in the controller always has the first element of the array, #ddd. I have even tried with ChangeBgColor('{{color}}'), too but that didin't help either. (Same result altough when inspecting the DOM I can see the different colors as string parameters.)

A better way would be to bind the selectedProduct.bgcolor property to the ng-repeat and let angular do the selection and changing when the user select an other color but I'm new to angular and this seems too much for a day.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/bu9r82ct/ is this not what your looking for. I don't see the problem

Comment: @StevenKaspar I have the same code and mine is not working. The one in your jsfiddle works, it passes the selected color into the method.

Comment: The first button seems like pushing when I click on an other button... Like they were radio buttons or something.

Comment: Do the rendered buttons at least have their background colors set according to array?

Comment: @TSmith yes they had their bgcolor from the aarray.The problem was that all the buttons were placed inside one label. I've changed the label to div and the buttons started to work. I don't know why however. I give the solution for the best explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I put all the buttons in one label:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Háttérszín</span>
    <button ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{'background-color':color}" ng-click="ChangeBgColor(color)"></button>
</label>
```

If I change the **label** to **div** it is working as expected. I don't understand, btw I use ionic just forgot to mention. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-style` directive for this.

```
 <button ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{'background-color':color}" ng-click="ChangeBgColor(color)"></button>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
    $scope.colors = ['#ddd', '#b2b2b2', '#0c60ee', '#0a9dc7', '#28a54c', '#e6b500', '#e42112', '#6b46e5', '#111', 'orange', 'yellow', 'maroon', 'green', 'brown', 'lightblue'];
  $scope.selectedProduct = {bgcolor:""};
 $scope.ChangeBgColor = function(selectedColor)
   {
     console.log(selectedColor);
     $scope.selectedProduct.bgcolor = selectedColor;  
   };
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   
  <div ng-style="{'background-color':selectedProduct.bgcolor}">
    This is a test!
  </div>  
  <button ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{'background-color':color}" ng-click="ChangeBgColor(color)">{{color}}</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for ng-style but the method still gets #ddd every time no matter which button I click on.

Comment: I'm sure that your code is perfect as it is like Steven's in jsfiddle. But mine still gives #ddd all the time. Interesting thing is when I push any button except #ddd, the first one still does something. Like they were radio buttons if I push eg the third one, the first seems to be changing, too. WTF?